# Would that be possible to add a JavaScript file to the page conditionally without using Server side code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, debug-symbols

I have 2 javascript files; Project.js and Project-debug.js.

When my ASP.NET is running in DEBUG mode the later should be loaded and when in RELEASE mode, the former.

Would that be possible to do something like this in html to add my script?

e.g.

```
<script src="iif(DEBUG,../Scripts/Project-debug.js,../Scripts/Project.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

[Conditionally Load external javascript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fileref = document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    if (DEBUG) {  
       fileref.setAttribute("src", "Project-debug.js");
    } else {
       fileref.setAttribute("src", "Project.js");
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
</script>
```

add this inside your head tag